# Автозавершение во вторичном командном окне

Tags: windows, cmd, bat

Вот у меня в папке документ 1.txt и 2 батника - 1.bat, 2.bat. Содержание 1.bat:

```
cd /d %0\.. 
start 2.bat
exit
```

Содержание 2.bat:

```
cd /d %0\.. 
del 1.txt
```

При запуске 1.bat запускается и второй, файл 1.txt удаляется, тут все ОК. Однако при нажатии в окне второго батника стрелки вверх заполнение предыдущей командой не происходит, вопреки обычному. Как сделать, чтобы это заполнение происходило?

Comment: Речь идёт о вызове списка предыдущих выполненных команд в интерпретаторе командной строки **cmd.exe**? Bat-файл, он же batch file - это пакетное выполнение команд. В экземпляре CMD.EXE, который выполняет bat-файл не работает этот функционал, пока не прекратится обработка пакетного файла.

Comment: Так а разве эта обработка не прекращается? Файл 1.bat - то закрывается.

Comment: Так 2-ое окно - это **новый** экземпляр **cmd.exe**. С какой стати в него должен переместиться список команд, выполненных в другом процессе? Команды, введенные в интерпретатор хранятся до тех пор, пока существует этот процесс и хранятся в области памяти выделенной ему. Строго говоря список этих команд может попасть в сведения слежения за системой, но это уже иная тема для обсуждения. Если нужен предыдущей экземпляр, уберите слово **start** из 2-ой строки файла **1.bat**. Тогда не будет создан новый экземпляр для исполнения **2.bat**

Comment: Убрал. Во-первых, при простом открытии 1.bat все закрывается, а, во-вторых, при запуске 1.bat  из командной строки, запущенной в папке с батниками, доступны только команды 1.bat и 2.bat. Команда же del 1.txt по-прежнему недоступна.

Comment: Команда **del 1.txt** вызывается не пользователем, а батником. Соответственно, появится в списке команд сама по себе она не может. В списке команд хранится только то, что набрал пользователь. Что касается закрытия cmd.exe после исполнения. Вызывайте его с ключом **/k**.Например, **cmd /k 1.bat**. Но смысл того, что Вам нужно не улавливаю никак.

Comment: Смотрите. Есть програ LyX (оболочка для ТеХ с одной стороны, с другой -  текстовой процессор, наподобие Ворд). В нее можно вводить команды через командную строку. Команда echo LYXCMD:vstgr:inset-apply:graphics filename 01.eps> \\.\pipe\lyxpipe.in, выполненная из командной строки, вставит в место, где мигает курсор в LyX, фотку 01.eps. Конечно, графику можно вставлять и "официальным способом" С третьей стороны, в LyX можно определить команду для запуска батника в папке файла, из которого этот батник вызывается. Но этот батник будет выполняться в скрытом режиме, в нем ничего не изменишь.

Comment: Вот я и думал первый батник вызывать из LyX, он бы вызывал второй батник, в котором выполнялась бы искаженная команда echo LYXCMD:vstgr:inset-apply:graphics filename > \\.\pipe\lyxpipe.in. Естественно, эта команда ничего бы не производила. Зато в окне второго батника нажимал бы стрелку вверх, дописывал имя фотки, Интер и вуа-ля, готово.

Comment: Параметризованная обработка bat-файлов используется переменные %1, %2, etc. Есть функция работы с входными переменными **SHIFT**. Подавайте входные параметры данных введенных пользователем внутрь функций bat-файлов. Делайте так, как Вам удобнее. Основные ограничения в **Windows batch**, как мне кажется, это сложность обработки переменных и немного архаичный функционал.  Впрочем, есть и другие средства Powershell,WSH и т.д.

Comment: Да, есть вариант в сторону JS: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1004952/%d0%a4%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5 , только ма-аленькая загвоздка.