# Фокусировка в уже запущенное приложение

Tags: javascript, wsh

Открыто окно программы LyX (в ней пишут). Нужно написать файл .js для выполнения в этом окне определенных команд. Но я не могу поместить эту программу в фокус. Знаю такое начало:

```
WshShell=WScript.
CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
theCalculator = WshShell.Exec("calc");           
// Запустим калькулятор
WScript.Sleep(3000);                             
// Ждем 3 секунды
WshShell.AppActivate
(theCalculator.ProcessID);   // Активируем окно запущенного приложения
```

Но там перемещается фокус в запущенную перед этим из этого же скрипта прогру. С другой стороны, понимаю, что нужно использовать [WScript.ConnectObject](http://www.plam.ru/compinet/windows_script_host_dlja_windows_2000_xp/p3.php11), только не знаю, как. Подскажите, плиз.

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Обнаружил такую фигню: вот запущен виндовский калькулятор, его PID 4156. Тогда код

```
var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.AppActivate("calc");
WScript.Sleep(100);
WshShell.SendKeys("1{+}");
WScript.Sleep(500);
WshShell.SendKeys("2");
WScript.Sleep(500);
WshShell.SendKeys("~");
WScript.Sleep(500);
WshShell.SendKeys("*3");
WScript.Sleep(500);
WshShell.SendKeys("~");
WScript.Sleep(2500);
```

ничего не делает. Код

```
var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.AppActivate("4156");
WScript.Sleep(100);
WshShell.SendKeys("1{+}");
WScript.Sleep(500);
WshShell.SendKeys("2");
WScript.Sleep(500);
WshShell.SendKeys("~");
WScript.Sleep(500);
WshShell.SendKeys("*3");
WScript.Sleep(500);
WshShell.SendKeys("~");
WScript.Sleep(2500);
```

делает то, что было задумано. И в то же время код

```
var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.AppActivate("word");
WScript.Sleep(100);
WshShell.SendKeys("1{+}");
WScript.Sleep(500);
WshShell.SendKeys("2");
WScript.Sleep(500);
WshShell.SendKeys("~");
WScript.Sleep(500);
WshShell.SendKeys("*3");
WScript.Sleep(500);
WshShell.SendKeys("~");
WScript.Sleep(2500);
```

тоже выполняет нужное (перед выполнением этого скрипта ворд уже запущен). Такое впечатление, как будто система не знает имен вживленных в нее же программ.

Answer (score 0):

метод Run пробовали?
Вот пример кода:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "calc.exe", 9

WScript.Sleep(3000)

WshShell.SendKeys "1"
WshShell.SendKeys "{+}"
WshShell.SendKeys "2"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

Есть замечание к функции **AppActivate**. Возможно, эта функция ищет ближайшее окно с указанным заголовком (в виде строкового параметра) и активирует его. То есть, она ищет окно по названию, а не по Id процесса.

Вообще управление состоянием окон через функции WSH невозможно. Но ничто не мешает импортировать необходимые функции WinAPI в скрипты и использовать их.
Как альтернатива, это использование внешних утилит на подобие [NirCMD](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html).

P.S. В приведенном примере не используется существующий процесс, а именно порождается новый процесс - так работает функция **Run**

Comment: Daemon-5, ваш код вызывает следующую ошибку: https://postimg.cc/dLBv28mk

Comment: Слушайте, а при чем здесь метод Run? Ведь он "Создает новый независимый процесс, который запускает приложение..." (http://www.plam.ru/compinet/windows_script_host_dlja_windows_2000_xp/p3.php) или в семерке все совсем по-другому?

Comment: Второй параметр метода Run, равный 9, предписывает развернуть минимизированное приложение и активировать его, то есть установить на него фокус.

Comment: По поводу ошибки. Приведенный код у файла скрипта имеет расширение **.vbs**, поэтому у меня выполняется без ошибок.

Comment: Daemon-5, а-а, так это другое дело, я и смотрю, код какой-то не свойственный JS. Но почему-то изготовленный из вашего кода файл .vbs не активизирует уже открытое окно калькулятора, а открывает новое и в нем выполняет все команды. А так файл отрабатывает без единой ошибки.